# create dataframe using the values from csv file, (Displays NaN values)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe by reading the CSV file but I want to create a new DataFrame using the existing dataframe and put files into it.So my created dataframe looks like this:
[image]

The code is :

```
import pandas as pd
df_csv = pd.read_csv('./mean_data.csv',names = ['A','B','C'] )
print(df_csv)
```

I am creating the new DataFrame using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_csv = pd.read_csv('./mean_data.csv',names = ['A','B','C'] )
df_we=pd.DataFrame(df_csv,columns=['TempOut','HiTemp','LowTemp','OutHum','WindSpeed','Rain'],index = df_csv['A'])
print(df_we)
```

But the output displays the value NaN . The out looks like this:
[image]